# String.class Split use in Camel-Context

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I'm trying to pass a comma delimited list of values to my camel-context and have it split into a list of Strings. This is what I have so far, but how do I pass my comma delimited list to it. So that this bean will return a list of Strings. I know I can write code for this and be done with it, but want to see if its doable without writing any code for it.

```
<bean id="nodesList" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="split" >
       <constructor-arg name="regex" value=","/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Camel is backed by Spring, which supports comma-delimited parameters out of the box. If you assign a String property to a collection-typed bean field, Spring should automatically attempt to split your property by commas

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example? @AlexSavitsky

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577547/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-specify-a-list-with-values-in-spring or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value - I believe this feature is available since Spring 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex Savitsky pointed out, his hyperlinks worked like a charm. Posting it here as the answer so others can see it.

"See [What is the easiest way to specify a list with values in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577547/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-specify-a-list-with-values-in-spring) or [Reading a List from properties file and load with spring annotation @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value) - I believe this feature is available since Spring 3.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by leveraging the [Tokenizer](https://camel.apache.org/tokenizer.html) that built into camel core. Your code would look something like this

```
from(START)
  .split(body().tokenize(","))
  .to(DEST)
```

Check the [Splitter documentation](https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) for more detailed examples.